# How is malicious code in being added to my WordPress site?

Tags: php, security

I have a WordPress site. There is some AdSense code in it which I didn't add. The code is located in the theme `footer.php` file, but whenever I upload a new file, the code gets inserted in it all over again.

How can I find which script keeps inserting this code in the file?

Or could it be that the server is infected with some kind of a virus? I'm on a shared host, by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've been hacked. Do not pass go. Do not edit your website further. You must treat all files as compromised and untrustworthy. Contact your hosting provider immediately.

Answer (score 2):

It is not granted it was your code that was hacked. Depending on how the hosting is set up, your files may be writable by others. Check that your files are only writable by your user, and make sure that the scripts are **not** writable by the user running the php scripts on the server.

The php files should only be writable by your user uid.

If your provider is running su-php then the malicious code is infect in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely contact your hosting provider.
And yes - theoretically it could be that there are more vHosts infected if your host is not from a professional hoster. But normally it should be secure (every vhost has his own user with whom the scripts will be executed - e. g. fastcgi).